# TestCafe selector for a textbox with same ID

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automation, testcafe

I am trying to type text in the textbox using selectors. However the textbox shares the same ID.
How can i index selectors. I was able to do it via xpath. However i need to pass it as selector

textbox id = #input1

Comment: What you've done so far?

Comment: This is how I am passing value to the 1st text box 
    const id_2 = 'input’;
    const val1 = '123';
    const inField = new dataPill(testcafe, `#${id_2}`);
    await inField.typeText(val1);

I need to pass value to the second text box which has same ID i.e #input. So I wanted to know how I can index it for second text box

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme)[lement IDs should be unique within the entire document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme). I recommend that you avoid using the same ID for several elements.

You might want to enumerate elements by their type (input). Refer to the [Enumerate Elements Identified by a Selector](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/examples-of-working-with-dom-elements.html#enumerate-elements-identified-by-a-selector) topic where this example is illustrated in action.